# How to add a -Choose something- from a DropDownList created out of an enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I followed [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx) to be able to create DropDownLists from several enums that we need in our ViewModels.

So far my code is looking like this:

```
public static class HtmlDropDownExtensions
{
    private static readonly SelectListItem [] SingleEmptyItem = new[]{new SelectListItem{Text = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty}};

public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownList<TEnum>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string modelPropertyName, TEnum selectedValue)
{
    Type baseEnumType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum));
    IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = GetSelectListItems(values, selectedValue, baseEnumType);

    return htmlHelper.DropDownList(modelPropertyName, items);
}

public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    Type enumType = GetNonNullableModelType(metadata);

    Type baseEnumType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
    IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = GetSelectListItems(values, metadata.Model, baseEnumType);

    if (metadata.IsNullableValueType)
        items = SingleEmptyItem.Concat(items);

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items);
}

private static Type GetNonNullableModelType(ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
{
    Type realModelType = modelMetadata.ModelType;

    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(realModelType);
    if(underlyingType != null)
        realModelType = underlyingType;

    return realModelType;
}

private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems<TEnum>(IEnumerable<TEnum> values, object selectedValue, Type underlyingType)
{
    return from value in values
           select new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = value.ToString(),
               Value = Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType).ToString(),
               Selected = (value.Equals(selectedValue))
           };
    }
}
```

Now what I need is to be able to have a first option that prompts the user to select an option, be blank or unselected or something since the fields are required and there cannot be any defaults.

**Update:** 
I was thinking that maybe the "EnumDropDownList" method could add the empty SelectListItem before creating the DropDownList and returning the string. I have not tried that yet but I'm thinking that there will be an error when the MVC enginge tries to bind that to the ViewModel since it will not be possible to parse that value into the ViewModel's enum property.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Insert the default item at start of the list: dropdownlist.Insert(0, defaultItem);

Comment: @MrFox: Sorry, correct me if I'm wrong but I think that would work only on a Web Forms solution, not on an MVC one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you already have everything implemented:

```
if (metadata.IsNullableValueType)
    items = SingleEmptyItem.Concat(items);
```

If the model's property is of type `Nullable<YourEnum>`, this code will add default item at the beginning of the DropDownList.

However, if the property does not allow nulls, the default value will not be rendered. And this is the correct behavior - user should be required to enter something and should not see any default items.

If you want to change the text of the default value, go the `SingleEmptyItem` definition:

```
private static readonly SelectListItem [] SingleEmptyItem = new[]{new SelectListItem{Text = "Your text here", Value = string.Empty}};
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly what I would have to do is to make all my enum properties nullable and create some kind of custom DataAnotaion required attribute to validate that the property is not null. Right? Is this the very best solution for this requirement or am I making things to complicated? Thank you so much for your thoughts.

Comment: If you do not want your enum properties to accept nulls then why would you want to add the empty value to the corresponding dropdowns? Personally I do not see any reason for this. However, if you still want the default values like "--Select--" in your dropdowns, but need to disallow nulls, then you can make enum properties as nullable, and decorate them with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute` attribute. Since your default value is "", this attribute will cause validation to fail and user will be required to select anything from the dropdown. Hope it helps!

Comment: Allow me to explain. I'm building an entry form in which there are lots of fields which are dropdowns made from enums. For example one field is Country of Birth. There cannot be any pre-selected country since the user could submit the form not only without him selecting his country of birth but sending the pre-selected one which would make our data incorrect. That's why I asked the question or am I overly complicating things?

Comment: Well, in your situation it does make sense. I think you can safely go with `Nullable<YourEnum>` required properties.